# how should i change a var to next sibling on click event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following script to traverse a list of elements with a class of blur doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current = $('.blur').first();
    $("#scroll-down").click(function(){
        $(current).toggleClass('blur-unfocused');
        current = $(current).next('.blur');
    });
});
</script>
```

How would you improve this script to traverse to the next item with a class blur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they could be anywhere on the page, I would store them all and iterate through them instead of just retrieving the first one and trying to locate the following one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $allBlurs = $('.blur');
    var currentIndex = 0;

    $("#scroll-down").click(function(){
        // Retrieve Current Blur
        var $current = $allBlurs.eq(currentIndex);

        // Increment Index (optionally looping)
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % $allBlurs.length;

        // Retrieve Next Blur 
        var $next = $allBlurs.eq(currentIndex);

        $current.toggleClass('blur-unfocused');
        /* ... more code here ... */
    });
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ump2m0n/)**

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current = $('.blur').first();
    $("#scroll-down").click(function(){
        $(current).toggleClass('blur-unfocused');
        current = $('.blur:not(.blur-unfocused)');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in an array and then traverse as needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var all = $('.blur');        
    if (all.length > 0) {
      var currentCount = 0;
      var current = all[currentCount];
      $("#scroll-down").click(function(){
          $(current).toggleClass('blur-unfocused');
          if (all.length > currentCount-1) {
            current = all[++currentCount];
          }
      });
    }
});
</script>
```